# Why is this simple Javascript refactor not working?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

A simple question about a form submit in HTML.

Why does this work:

```
var inputStuff = document.getElementById("inputBox");
var output = document.getElementById("outputBox");

function useMethod(element) {

    output.innerText = inputStuff.value;
    return false; 
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
var inputStuff = document.getElementById("inputBox");
var output = document.getElementById("outputBox");

function useMethod(element) {
    var out = output.innerText;
    var into = inputStuff.value;

    out = into;
    return false; 
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<h1>Put your input in here</h1>
    <form onsubmit="return useMethod(this)" action="">
        <input type="text" id="inputBox">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Output:</h2>
    <p id="outputBox">Starter text</p>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help,

R

Comment: What's the purpose of refactoring? What do you want from the code?

Comment: you are using a primitive type (mainly `into`) and you lose the object reference.

Comment: HI guys, thanks for replies - this is just to clarify for me how to use forms properly. the basic page is for testing out javascript methods

Comment: Nina - thanks so much, didn't know into was a reserved word, I'll try and change it

Comment: `into` is not a reserve word. it is just a variable with a primitive type.

Comment: OK I understand now. When i did out = into I wasn't actually asking the DOM to be changed, I was simply saying that this is the same as that - i.e it worked on a basic level in the javascript but didn't actually do anything... hope I've got it right

Answer (score 4):

`out = into;` will simply assign the value of `into` (string) to `out` (string), whereas `output.innerText = inputStuff.value;` will invoke an **implicit setter** that will change the DOM value as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, since String is a primitive value.